# Is there a way to share the Eclipse task list within svn repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Is there a way to share the Eclipse task list within svn repository?

Comment: You need this because other people may/are not using Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a bit heavyweight but you could use [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) to share tasks. It comes with almost any version of Eclipse now.

Here is a thread about [sharing local tasks](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.mylyn/msg00475.html) (not recommended by Mylyn's creator) vs. using a free trac or bugzilla instance to share the tasks (look at the root post to get even more alternatives).

Comment: Mylyn isn't that havyweight, plus gives additional features. You could even share your task contexts with others.